# How to save the output of Docker Build to std out?

Tags: docker, terminal, stdout, docker-registry

when I try to either pipe the output of docker build to a text file or to read it with popen in a script -- I'm not able to. It seems to not be writing to stdout but I can still see the output on terminal. What could possibly be going on here? I've tried various flags including --progress=plain but that still doesn't print to std out. The only flag that seems to print something to std out is -q which only prints the image ID. We'd ideally need the entire build output.

This is with build kit enabled.

Comment: Did you try `docker build -t NAME:TAG . > some_file`?

Comment: Yup @Saeed, unfortunately that returns an empty file for any of the containers we have.

Comment: I tried a test docker build in my local and it worked. What if you enter `docker build -t NAME:TAG .`? Does it return anything in stdout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following up with an answer that worked for us here:

With build kit enabled, docker build's output is printing to stderr instead of stdout. Adding 2>&1 fixed the issue with us. This is currently a bug for docker.

[Bug Info](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1186)